# MATLAB: Does the If Statement order affect performance

Tags: performance, matlab, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to speed up a loop that runs for about 100000 iterations and was wondering if the order of if statements had an effect on the performance. For example will the following code check the if and elseif before executing the statements in else every time it goes through the for loop?

```
for ii = 1:100000

    if ii == 1
        statements_1;
    elseif ii >= 2 && ii <= 10
        statements_2;
    else
        statements_3;
    end
end
```

Will the below code run faster?

```
for ii = 1:100000

    if ii > 10
        statements_3;
    elseif ii >= 2 && ii <= 10
        statements_2;
    else
        statements_1;
    end
end
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: In a chain of if/elseifs, the condition placed first should be the one that you expect to be the most likely to succeed, the condition placed second should be the second most likely to succeed, and so on.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware of it, look into the `tick` and `tock` commands for timing functions. They are very useful for optimizing! MATLAB also has a great profiler but that wouldn't help as much here.

Comment: @chessofnerd `tic` and `toc`, no 'k'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will check the first condition fist, and then if it is false, it will check the following conditions.

However, to improve performance, I suggest you to use a more vectorized code:

```
for i=find(condition1(1:10000))
  statements1
end

for i=find(condition2(1:10000))
  statements2
end

for i=find(condition3(1:10000))
  statements3
end
```

with for instance `condition2=@(i) (i>2 & i<10)`

Comment: That vectorized version is only really suitable if `statement3(i)` is not a function of `statement2(j)` or `statement1(k)`, i.e., a recurrence relation. Otherwise you'll need to pass around data to make that work.

Comment: +1 That's a potentially very useful programming pattern for MATLAB.

Comment: I am sorry, but I believe that your solution is much slower than the original single loop. The reason is that on modern ML releases, the JITC/accelerator is able to nearly vectorize the loop, whereas in your solution you repeat the loop three times, each time using find() on the entire vector, which is wasteful in memory alloc/dealloc and CPU. Try it and see for yourself.

A better solution would be to fully vectorize the loop (i.e., remove the use of the ``for`` keyword) if this is possible.

Comment: @YairAltman, of course full vecorization is always the faster solution in matlab. But the question was about executing generic code that may or may not be vectorizable. In my answer, the cost of the find() should be very small in almost all cases, compared to the execution of the statements. If the statement are very very simple, indeed, another solution should be preferred.

Comment: @Oli - I was well aware of this. Still, the find() approach is often _less_ efficient than a loop. Consider the following code:
    tic
    a = [0,0,0];
    for idx = 1 : 1e7
      if mod(idx,17)==0
        a(1) = a(1) + 1;
      elseif mod(idx,23)==0
        a(2) = a(2) + 1;
      else
        a(3) = a(3) + 1;
      end
    end
    toc

    tic
    a = [0,0,0];
    for idx = find(mod(range,17)==0);
      a(1) = a(1) + 1;
    end
    for idx = find(mod(range,23)==0);
      a(2) = a(2) + 1;
    end
    for idx = find(mod(range,17)~=0 & mod(range,23)~=0);
      a(3) = a(3) + 1;
    end
    toc